# Can't Deploy Report Models in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I created a data model in BIDS for SSRS 2008 SP1. When I try to deploy, I get the following error:

Exception of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsProxy.AccessDeniedException' was thrown.

When I Googled the issue, all I can find is information such as this:

> 1. Open “Report Manager” using http:///reports;
> 2. Click “Site Settings”;
> 3. Click :Configure item-level role definitions”;
> 4. Click “Content Manager”;
> 5. Make sure everything is ticked off especially “Manage models” and “ View
>      models”;

However, when I open my Report Manager URL, number 3 doesn't apply. I am an admin on this machine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the answer of click BIDS and Select "Run As Administrator".  This didn't work for me.  The model would not deploy, but I did manage to go past the Exception of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsProxy.AccessDeniedException' was thrown.

This is what I ended up doing to resolve the issue:

- Right Click on BIDS and choose "Run As Administrator"
- Change the Target URL under Project => PROJECTNAME Properties to an https URL.

Now, the report did deploy, but I am not able to open the report page. I receive a Reporting Services Error that the permissions granted to user... are insufficient for performing this operation. I am still working on that. However; I wanted to post what I did know in case it helps any other people new to this as I am.

UPDATE:  For whatever reason, instead of the report page appearing, I had to type it into the browser and then it would work.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh. When I right click Bids and select "Run As Administrator" the Model deploys perfectly.

Ugh.